# Extending characters on subgroups

Tags: group-theory, characters

In these notes, http://sporadic.stanford.edu/bump/group/gr2_2.html, I don't understand why there's a need for Proposition 2.2.1 in view of Lemma 2.2.3 (which comes before).  I thought Lemma 2.2.3 says "if we have a character $\chi $ on a proper subgroup $H$ of $G$, then we can extend $\chi $ to a group $J$ such that $H\subset J\subseteq G$".  (All groups here are finite (and abelian) by the way).

But maybe I'm interpreting this wrong and getting confused about largest/maximal sets or something like this?  Why can't we just keep applying the above lemma until we reach $G$?

Comment: You can. Proposition 2.2.1 is proved in  the way you describe.

Comment: is that what happens?  i wasn't sure.  thanks!

Comment: I think you agree with the author. "Keep applying Lemma 2.2.3" is the proof given for Proposition 2.2.1. The main difference between them is that in 2.2.3 that subgroup J=K is not under your control: it can only be a subgroup generated by H and a single element x. Click on "Click to expand/collapse" to see the proofs given.